# Tool for recording GDI handle leaks

Tags: windows, software-testing, debugging

An application has GDI Leaks, which I detected with [NirSoft GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html). Now that I know there is a GDI Handle leak, I need a more professional tool with the following properties:

- works on Windows 7 and higher
- has 32 and 64 bit support
- records GDI handle leaks with call stack
- costs less than 500 €
- has prices available on the website, not on request
- has a GUI to start tracking, stop tracking and selecting the target application

I used to know BoundsChecker, but that is outdated and seems to be integrated into [Micro Focus DevPartner](https://www.microfocus.com/products/devpartner) for which the price is on request.

I have tried:

- [GDIDebug (SourceForge)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ideatester/files/gdidebug/), but it was last updated in 2005 and either it does not work any more (perhaps due to 64 bit) or I'm just too stupid to use it.
- [LeakMon (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/150463/leakmon-track-handle-leak-gdi-leak-and-memory-leak), but after the link to Google drive, it tells me that I'm not allowed to download infected files.
- [Rohitab API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), which I used with a [list of methods](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/175591/leakmon-part-2-under-the-hood.aspx). This basically works, but it does not associate the creation and the deletion of GDI objects with each other, so I can't ditinguish between a leak from a non-leak
- [Bear](https://www.the-sz.com/products/bear/) would be great, but it has a constant usage of 1 logical processor on my machine (Windows 10 x64). Its reaction time is too slow. It needs almost a second to display a context menu or similar.

Comment: If your application is open source and in C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript Ruby or Python then https://scan.coverity.com/ may well be able to spot the source of the problem from static analysis.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: thanks. Unfortunately it's a mix of several programming languages, including VB6, and it's not open source.

Comment: [Deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/) should be able to do that, but I have never used it.